# ASP.NET MVC 5 publishing only controller doesn't update on host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, publishing

There's probably a very logic answer to this question. If I update a controller and publish it to my webhost, the updated part doesn't seem to work, it looks like it didn't update the controller. However, when I publish my whole project everything works fine.

Not a big issue but publishing your whole site for just a little controller update seems like wasted time. Any explanations?

Comment: You don't publish code itself to a web server. When you build your project, it is the files in `bin/` directory that matter.

Comment: you can update only static files (`.css`, `.js`, `.html`) without republishing. The `.cs` code is compiled so you need to republish the application or build the project and copy the `.dll` from the `/bin/` folder.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work

- first Rebuild project on VS
- then replace  YourProjectName.dll and  YourProjectName.dll.config on bin file to your host
- then replace the controller you want